# Spring Security 4.0.3 rememberMe tokenValiditySeconds not working

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, spring-rest

I have specified a `tokenValiditySeconds` of 1 in my Spring Security Config but I keep seeing the default of 1209600 (found in `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices`) show up.  I have a custom "RememberMeService" class that extends `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` (which in turn extends `AbstractRememberMeServices`) but I'm not altering the `tokenValiditySeconds` in my class...I'm just expecting it to be set from my Security Config.

Everything else is working fine except the `tokenValiditySeconds`.  I am using this specifically for my REST API (rather than in a web form).

How do I make the `tokenValiditySeconds` I specify in my Spring Security Config apply in my RememberMeService?  Here is my `configure()` method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .sameOrigin()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .httpBasic()
        .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .key(KEY)
            .tokenValiditySeconds(1)
            .userDetailsService(springUserDetailsService)
            .rememberMeServices(new SpringRememberMeService(KEY, springUserDetailsService))
        .and()
            .logout().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to specify `tokenValiditySeconds` in my `SpringRememberMeService` class instead of in the `rememberMe()` configurer and this is working fine. Note that I'm overriding a couple of classes in `TokenBasedRememberMeServices` for our specific needs.

```
package com.avada.rest.security;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

public class SpringRememberMeService extends TokenBasedRememberMeServices {

    public static final int TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 60 * 30; // 30 minutes

    public SpringRememberMeService(String key, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        super(key, userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected String extractRememberMeCookie(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String rememberMe = request.getHeader("remember-me");
        int startIndex = "remember-me=".length();
        int endIndex = rememberMe.indexOf("; ", startIndex);
        return rememberMe.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    }

    @Override
    protected int calculateLoginLifetime(HttpServletRequest request, Authentication authentication) {
        return TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS;
    }
}
```